# How to automate export of Selenium IDE scripts into rspec

Tags: selenium, rspec, selenium-ide, rspec-rails

I have a QA person creating Selenium scripts inside Selenium IDE for Rails 3 app.

I am trying to find way to automate the export from Selenium IDE into rspec so they will be run automatically on our CI server. Basically, I don't want to manually export scripts from Selenium IDE. Has anyone done this or have suggestions on an approach?

Thanks.
-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export your selenium test to rspec. But you need to install another firefox add on call [php formatters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/).

When you had installed this add on your firefox, you can convert your selenium ide tests to rspec.